# Is there a way to wait for ALL angular 2 components to be rendered?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on an Angular 2 app that has a good amount of routes and guards. I also have an Angular component that has to set the height of something based on the current height of a div. The problem is when I break on the setting of this height, I noticed my header hasn't been rendered yet (I am still looking into life cycle around this.), so the height I am getting changes after the header is rendered. I am currently calling the height setting function in `ngAfterViewInit`. Is there another way to handle this in a way that all components are initially rendered before I run the code?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `NgZone`s `onStable`/`isStable` see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html#!#onStable-anchor